# Error al ejecutar AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

Tengo un problema al tratar de añadir la url para parsear me sale un error de `FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1` y no entiendo por qué.

Así es como parseo los datos:

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TMOLectorAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> tmoLectorClases = new ArrayList<>();
    private String url = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_t_m_o_lector);

        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new TMOLectorAdapter(tmoLectorClases, TMOLector.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Content content = new Content();
        content.execute();
    }

    private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, ArrayList<TMOLectorClase>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> items) {
            super.onPostExecute(items);
            //Actualizar información
            adapter.updateData(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            tmoLectorClases.clear();
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("div");

                for (Element e : data) {
                    String urlRedireccionada = e.select("div.OUTBRAIN").attr("data-src");
                    try {

                        doc = Jsoup.connect(urlRedireccionada).get();

                        Elements dataNuevo = doc.select("div.img-container.text-center");
                        for (Element e1 : dataNuevo) {
                            String imgUrl = e1.select("img").attr("src");
                            tmoLectorClases.add(new TMOLectorClase(imgUrl));
                        }
                    }  catch (IOException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return tmoLectorClases;
        }
    }
```

El error me `LogCat` me marca esta línea:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(urlRedireccionada).get();
```

Con el error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL
```

Lo que sucede es que esta `url`, se convierte en esta `urlRedireccionada` y trato de cargar imágenes desde la `urlRedireccionada` en un `RecyclerView`. ¿Alguien me podría decir como solucionarlo? Debugee el còdigo y pues, la url si es vàlida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues lo he solucionado de esta forma, primero creo un `String` que obtenga la url redireccionada:

```
String nuevaUrl = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true).execute().url().toExternalForm();
```

Luego se lo asigno al `Document`:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(nuevaUrl).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal es que tratas de obtener la url que proviene de un Intent dentro del AsyncTask, lo cual es incorrecto

```
@Override
        protected ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
            ...
            ...
```

El valor de `url` debe obtenerse dentro del método `onCreate()` y este valor podrás usarlo en toda tu Activity:

```
 private String url = "";

 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ...
            ...
            url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        }
```

Comment: Una pregunta, el valor de la `url` que está en el `onCreate` lo puedo aplicar dentro de otro método?

Comment: Claro, si defines una variable de clase private String url  = ""; al obtener el valor en onCreate y asignarlo a url, lo puedes usar dentro de cualquier método,

Comment: Pues, no. Se me sigue cerrando la aplicación y el error es el mismo. He añadido el código de toda la actividad a lo mejor se me escapa un detalle que no estoy viendo

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo pero cual es el error, revisa donde diga "Caused by" en el LogCat

Comment: Pues, era el mismo `Must supply a valir url `

Comment: donde esta el AsyncTask es un  Activity?, si es así como envias a esa activity el valor de url?

Comment: Ya lo solucioné creando un string que obtiene la urlredireccionada y aplicandola a un nuevo document, la puse abajo